# How to include a value from .env file in Rails into javascript tag using Slim Framework

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

Consider we have an ENV defined in the Rails .env file and we want to use that in the .html.slim file under the Javascript section

.env file

```
NUMBER_TO_MULTIPLY: 2
```

filename.html.slim

```
javascript:
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var count = selectedRows.length; // Gives me value as 3
    var totalCount = count * "#{ENV['NUMBER_TO_MULTIPLY']}" // Should give me value as 3 * 2 = 6
    alert(totalCount) // Produces me 0 as the result 
  }
```

I tried Rails.env but it give the value as "development" apart from that I am not able to access any value from the ENV. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`.env` files arent supported by Rails out of the box.

For development / test the [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) gem is an alternative.

For production it depends on the hosting environment.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am using "dot-env" gem only - gem 'dotenv-rails', '2.8.1' in the development environment

Comment: Ok, that changes the question to "why isnt dotenv-rails" working.. You sure the syntax in the .env file is right? Looks like it should be `NUMBER_TO_MULTIPLY=2` judging by the docs

Comment: Yes I do have some other code in the .env file following the same structure and I am  accessing it in the other .erb file as I mentioned in the above question like ENV['NUMBER_TO_DIVIDE']